# Hamiltonian cycle in $C_n^k$ in polynomial time for constant $k$?

Tags: hamiltonian-path, hamiltonian-circuit

Let $C_n$ denote the cycle graph over $n$ vertices. Let $C_n^k$ denote the [$k$-th power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power) of the cycle graph, or namely that for two vertices $i,j$, $(i,j)\in Edges(C_n^k) \iff |i-j|\leq k$ for a constant $k$.

Now given a subgraph $G$ of $C_n^k$, how can we find a hamiltonian cycle (if it exists) in $G$ in polynomial time (in $n$)?

I've tried solving this with DP but the best I've reached is $O(2^nn)$ which just matches the known DP for hamiltonian cycle. I would prefer hints over full answers.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami done (They are vertices, and $ij$ represents an edge)

Comment: @InuyashaYagami $C_n$ is a cycle with vertices $1,2,...,n$. $C_n^k$ is a graph with vertices $1,2,...,n$ and edges $(i,i-k \mod n), (i, i-k+1 \mod n), ..., (i, i-1), (i, i+1 \mod n), ..., (i, i+k \mod n)$  for all i

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Yes exactly, thank you

Comment: Is the algorithm of the form $O(n^k)$ allowed?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Yes, I am looking for something polynomial time in $n$ and constant $k$, so it would work

Answer (score 1):

Addressing [another](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/143611/107966) question of OP:

Suppose $k$ is equal to $n$. If so, then $C_{n}^{k}$ would be a complete graph. And, suppose if we could check if a Hamiltonian cycle exists in any subgraph $G$ of $C_n^{k}$ in polynomial time (i.e., $poly(n,k)$), then it would mean that we can solve [Hamiltonian Cycle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) in polynomial time on any graph with $n$ vertices.

Since the Hamiltonian Cycle problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard; therefore, the stated problem is also $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. In other words, it is hard to find a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$ in time polynomial in $k$ and $n$.

Comment: As specified in the question, $k$ is a *constant*.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yeah, you are right. That I know. I was addressing [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/143611/107966) question of OP.

Comment: I see. You should have made it clear that you are not answering the original question. Even so, I'm pretty sure the OP *knows* that Hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete. While the formulation in their answer is not quite clear, I believe that what they are asking is if the problem can be solved in time where the dependency on $k$ cannot appear in the exponent: $f(k)n^{c}$ for some constant $c$ and a function $f$. Iow, if Ham Cycle is fixed-parameter tractable with $k$ being the parameter. Your answer does not address that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overkill solution:

Lemma: The subgraph $G$ has tree-width at most $2k$.

*Proof.* Treat all additions and subtractions in what follows in circular modulo arithmetic (for example $n+1 = 1$). Also assume $n\gg k$. Let $L_j=\{j-1, j-2, ..., j-2k\}$ and $R_j=\{j+1, ..., j+2k\}$. Then the path decomposition for $C_n^k$ of $(L_1\cup \{1\}\cup R_1), (L_1\cup \{2\} \cup R_2), (L_1\cup\{3\}\cup R_3), ...$ is a path (tree) decomposition with width $2k$, and so the tree-width of $C_n^k$ is at most $2k$ so a subgraph of $C_n^k$ has tree-width at most $2k$.

Since the tree-width of $G$ is at most $2k$, then there is a $O(n^{O(k)})$ algorithm that finds a nice tree decomposition $T$ for $G$. We can then run the FPT hamiltonian cycle algorithm on $T$ to find a hamiltonian cycle for $G$ in $O(k^{O(k)}n)$ time.

Overall, the algorithm takes $O(n^{O(k)})$, which is polynomial time. I would still be interested in a polynomial time solution without a $k$ dependency, or even with dependency $k$ but simpler.

Comment: Without $k$ dependency, the problem is NP-hard.

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check if it makes sense.

Comment: I’m not sure where you got the $n^{O(k)}$ dependency. Tree decomposition can be found in FPT time linear in $n$. And anyway, Courcelle’s theorem directly says that Hamiltonian cycle, which is an $\mathrm{MSO}_2$ property, is solvable in time $O(f(k)n)$ on graphs of treewidth $\le k$, without assuming that it is presented with a tree decomposition.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Coucelle’s theorem applies to decision problems rather then search problems. But anyway, we can construct a Hamiltonian path by binary search using $n$ queries of the form “can a given path in $G$ be completed to a Hamiltonian cycle”, which are FPT linear in $n$; thus, the whole algorithm takes time $O(f(k)n^2)$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks, I am new to studying FPT, so I didn't know that trees can be found in FPT linear time!

Comment: Yes. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth#Computing_the_treewidth for some references.